How do I make LLVM find files that it thinks are in the wrong spot?
I'm trying to create a compiler using LLVM. I understand some LLVM and I have experience creating compilers, but I'm fairly new to C++, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.
When including LLVM source files, I have a line that looks like this: #include <llvm-12/llvm/Pass.h>. (Yes, I'm aware that it's three years old.) Pass.h is arbitrary in this case, but it's the first file my eyes found when looking through the directory, and other files have the same problem.
This works fine - as in, the file is found and included. However, LLVM is trying to include files within the library. For example, from Pass.h, I get the error: 'llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h' not found. And including a file like llvm-12/llvm/IR/Value.h (a file I actually need), I get the error 'llvm-c/Types.h' file not found.
The files are all in the library in /usr/include/llvm-12/llvm/some_path_here. How do I make LLVM find the files?

Add a -I option pointing to the llvm-12 directory, then the files will be foiund. (#include "foo" tries the current directory first and then the include path.)

@arnt That does answer my direct question, and it almost works - LLVM is still missing the llvm-c folder, which it seems to expect to be in the same place as the llvm library (even though it isn't).
